# SQL SERVER 2005 OFFSET

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to apply offset to this query on SQL2005?

```
SELECT [name],[phone] 
FROM (
      SELECT *,Row_Number() Over (Partition By phone Order By (Select Null)) AS RN
      FROM Table1
      ) AS T
Where RN = 1
```

Thanks

Comment: `Partition By phone Order By (Select Null)` Doesn't guarantee any particular ordering. So there is absolutely no guarantee that `RN BETWEEN 10 AND 20` won't return the same rows as `RN BETWEEN 20 AND 30`

Answer (score 1):

OFFSET isn't supported in mssql 2005, but you can use following approuch to do this. 
if you that to select 10 record from 90 to 100 which was before sorted by name, you can use following query

```
;with data as
(
    SELECT [name],[phone] 
    FROM (
      SELECT *,Row_Number() Over (Partition By phone Order By (Select Null)) AS RN
      FROM Table1
      ) AS T
    Where RN = 1
)
select * from 
    (   select top(10) * from 
            (   select top(100) * from data order by name asc ) 
        t1 order by name desc 
    ) t2 order by name
```

Comment: how to get the records say from 20 to 30 then?

Comment: change select top(100) to select top(30)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by myself. I use this query (with different column names)

```
with CTE as (
   SELECT cFullname,BuyerPhoneNumber 
    FROM (
      SELECT *,Row_Number() Over (Partition By BuyerPhoneNumber Order By (Select Null)) AS RN
      FROM [Order]
      ) AS T
    Where RN = 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM (
SELECT  Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY cFullname ASC) AS CI_offset_row_number, *
FROM CTE
) AS A 
WHERE A.CI_offset_row_number BETWEEN (21) AND (30)
```